# Is there a faster way for false dropping grouping variables in R using dplyr package?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

```
library(tidyverse)
date = seq(as.Date("2022/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 16)
value = c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.7,1.4,1.9,1.89,2,2.1,2.2,2.15,3,3.1,3.09,2.08)
variable = c(rep("a",4),rep("b",4),rep("c",4),rep("d",4))
df = tibble(date,value,variable);df


# A tibble: 16 × 3
   date       value variable
   <date>     <dbl> <chr>   
 1 2022-01-01  1.1  a       
 2 2022-01-02  1.2  a       
 3 2022-01-03  1.3  a       
 4 2022-01-04  1.4  a       
 5 2022-01-05  1.7  b       
 6 2022-01-06  1.4  b       
 7 2022-01-07  1.9  b       
 8 2022-01-08  1.89 b       
 9 2022-01-09  2    c       
10 2022-01-10  2.1  c       
11 2022-01-11  2.2  c       
12 2022-01-12  2.15 c       
13 2022-01-13  3    d       
14 2022-01-14  3.1  d       
15 2022-01-15  3.09 d       
16 2022-01-16  2.08 d
```

I want to summarize the max and the min of the value column grouped by the variable column and match the corresponding date of these stats.

Doing so (using tidyverse package) I did :

```
df%>%group_by(variable)%>%
  summarise(MAX = max(value),MIN=min(value))%>%
  pivot_longer(!variable, names_to = "stats", values_to = "value")%>%
  left_join(.,df,by=c("value","variable"))



# A tibble: 8 × 4
  variable stats value date      
  <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <date>    
1 a        MAX    1.4  2022-01-04
2 a        MIN    1.1  2022-01-01
3 b        MAX    1.9  2022-01-07
4 b        MIN    1.4  2022-01-06
5 c        MAX    2.2  2022-01-11
6 c        MIN    2    2022-01-09
7 d        MAX    3.1  2022-01-14
8 d        MIN    2.08 2022-01-16
```

but I wonder is there a faster way for doing that matching for dates stats ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifying the min and max rows with the very efficient `which.min` and `which.max` function and keeping those rows with `slice` will be more efficient than summarizing and joining. (Should also be more efficient than reordering the whole data frame.)

```
df %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  slice(c(which.min(value), which.max(value))) %>%
  mutate(stat = c("MIN", "MAX")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 × 4
#   date       value variable stat 
#   <date>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
# 1 2022-01-01  1.1  a        MIN  
# 2 2022-01-04  1.4  a        MAX  
# 3 2022-01-06  1.4  b        MIN  
# 4 2022-01-07  1.9  b        MAX  
# 5 2022-01-09  2    c        MIN  
# 6 2022-01-11  2.2  c        MAX  
# 7 2022-01-16  2.08 d        MIN  
# 8 2022-01-14  3.1  d        MAX
```

Comment: This is nice. For n = 10M I see improvement from 1.5sec in OP to 0.17sec here. My approach was not consistently faster than OP.  Ran using sample data: `n = 1E7; set.seed(42); df <- tibble(  date = as.Date("2022-01-01") + rpois(n, 10),  value = rpois(n, 20) / 10,  variable = rep(letters[1:10], each = n / 10))`